# How can we get different stats behind a plotly boxplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, plotly

I'd like to get the exact stats behind a plotly boxplot.

This seems to get me pretty close, but I'm missing Q1 and Q3.

```
stats = df.groupby(['Market'])['Revenue'].describe()
stats
```

The Q1 and Q3 seem to be different than what I see from this.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.box(df, x="Market", y="Revenue", color="Market")
fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive")
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

It has something to do with the 'exclusive' or 'inclusive' argument, but I don't know what the difference is. Also, the default for `df.groupby(['Market'])['Revenue'].describe()` seems to match the 'inclusive' argument.

Q1: what's the difference between 'exclusive' and 'inclusive'?

Q2: does `df.groupby(['Market'])['Revenue'].describe()` have an 'exclusive' argument?

Comment: If you have a small number of points you'll see a difference. Seems to be explained here: https://plotly.com/r/box-plots/#choosing-the-algorithm-for-computing-quartiles. `describe` is definitely using `linear` interpolation by default since it calls `Series/DataFrame.quantile`

Comment: Kind of makes sense, but I saw some weirdness too, maybe because of the odd and even samples. Ok. Thanks.

Comment: Like you, I went to Yale too, but I only stayed there for one semester, because it was too expensive for me. The costs just outweighed the benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**

I haven't found a description in the plotly docs, but it's fair to assume that the explanation would not differ much from [Percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile):

> In statistics, a percentile (or a centile) is a score below which a
> given percentage of scores in its frequency distribution falls
> (exclusive definition) or a score at or below which a given percentage
> falls (inclusive definition). For example, the 50th percentile (the
> median) is the score below which (exclusive) or at or below which
> (inclusive) 50% of the scores in the distribution may be found.

You can take a closer look at a visual representation of the differences under [Difference Between Quartile Algorithms](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#difference-between-quartile-algorithms) in the plotly docs:

[image]

**Q2**

No, `df.describe()` does not seem to have an `exclusive` argument:

> Help on method describe in module pandas.core.generic:
>
> describe(percentiles=None, include=None, exclude=None,
> datetime_is_numeric=False) -> ~FrameOrSeries method of
> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame instance

As you can see, it does however have `include` and `exclude`. But they do very different things from what you're looking for:

> include : 'all', list-like of dtypes or None (default), optional
> A white list of data types to include in the result. Ignored
> for `Series`. Here are the options:
>
> ```
>     - 'all' : All columns of the input will be included in the output.
>     - A list-like of dtypes : Limits the results to the
>       provided data types.
>       To limit the result to numeric types submit
>       ``numpy.number``. To limit it instead to object columns submit
>       the ``numpy.object`` data type. Strings
>       can also be used in the style of
>       ``select_dtypes`` (e.g. ``df.describe(include=['O'])``). To
>       select pandas categorical columns, use ``'category'``
>     - None (default) : The result will include all numeric columns.
> ```

> ```
> exclude : list-like of dtypes or None (default), optional,
>     A black list of data types to omit from the result. Ignored
>     for ``Series``. Here are the options:
>
>     - A list-like of dtypes : Excludes the provided data types
>       from the result. To exclude numeric types submit
>       ``numpy.number``. To exclude object columns submit the data
>       type ``numpy.object``. Strings can also be used in the style of
>       ``select_dtypes`` (e.g. ``df.describe(include=['O'])``). To
>       exclude pandas categorical columns, use ``'category'``
>     - None (default) : The result will exclude nothing.
> ```

Comment: Looks awesome! Thanks for sharing this!!

Comment: @ASH Wasn't much, but hopefully what you were looking for!